# Why is my view in backbone not rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I am trying to render this template from my backbone views but it is not working? Anyone know what I am doing wrong here thanks! I will include my jade file for the views and the main.js file for the backbone js script.

Jade File

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")

        h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
            div#user
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit



        script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userEditTemplate", type ="text/template")
            div
                form(action="#")
                    input(type="text", class="firstName", value=#{firstName}) input(type="text", class="lastName", value=#{lastName})
                    input(type="email", class="email", value=#{email})
                    input(type="number", class="phone", value=#{phone})
                    input(type="date", class="birthday", value=#{birthday})
                button.save Save
                button.cancel Cancel
        hr
```

Main.Js file

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
             user.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
            });
        }

    });



    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.Models.User,
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',
        template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html());
        editTemplate: _.template($("#userEditTemplate").html());


        initialize: function (){

        }

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
        //  'click button.save': 'saveEdits',
            'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
        },

        editProfile: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

        },

cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({el: 'div #user'});
    user.render();
})();
```

Comment: Check your selector: 'div #user' or 'div#user'?

Comment: div#user is how you call it in jade... or am I doing something wrong

Comment: The selector `'div #user'` means `id="user"` inside a `<div>`, `<div id="user">` would be `div#user` or just `#user` is fine since `id` attributes must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you didn't assign backbone view a model.

So you could try this:

```
      var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        }
    });

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#user",
        model: MyModel,
        template: _.template($("#test-template").html()),
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var myView = new MyView({model:new MyModel()});
    myView.render();
```

And test-template is:

```
<script id="test-template" type="text/template">
   <div><%=name%></div>
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="user">
</div>
</body>
```

You can define backbone view's el attribute in Backbone view declaration. And remember to assign view a model when you initiate it.

[EDIT]

JADE:

```
script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
            p #{firstName} #{lastName}
            p #{email}
            p #{phone}
            p #{birthday}
            button.edit Edit
```

Modify template generation method:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/weepy/jade-browser/master/jade.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/weepy/jade-browser/master/jade-shim.js"></script>

template: jade.compile($("#userTemplate").text());
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I tried adding the model in the new view and moving the el to inside the view but it is still not working for me.

Comment: good call, getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined underscore.min.js:1
w.template underscore.min.js:1
(anonymous function) main.js:56  template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html()),
     
(anonymous function) main.js 112 })();

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your template declaration.

Comment: I see that too, but not sure what is wrong, I tried commenting it out of the window.App the templates{} but the error is still there...

Comment: I did that originally that doesnt work in Jade it has to be #{name}

Comment: #{name} means you will pass a object which contains property name to Jade compile function. But backbone's default template engine is underscore. If you want to bind the model to a view's template then your html template should in <%=property%> format.

Comment: Right but the <%= %> does not work in jade... there has to be another solution or should I look into handlebar?

Comment: @Lion789: a "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" error usually means that you're calling `_.template` with `$(x).html()` as an argument when there is no `x` in the DOM so `$(x).html()` is `undefined`; the usual solution is to defer the template compilation until after the DOM is all ready.

Comment: how do I go about doing that? I am confused because there is an id for usertemplate which exists in jade? I even tried to change the id to a div that is there #user but it still doesnt render and gives me the same error.

Comment: What is the bottom part, am I suppose to add that template generation method

Comment: I figured it out. switched to handlebar and used {{firstName}} instead of #{firstName}